# How can I make some elements position fixed after collapsible menu?

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

[image]

"sign in" & "sign up" options are going with the items of collapsible menu when I click on toogler icon. I want "sign in" . "sign up" options always in this position as it is.

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
     <div class="container" >

              <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ourNav">
                      <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
             </button>
                    <a href="" class="navbar-brand "> online exam </a>


                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center " id="ourNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Your Profile</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Exam</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item "><a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </div>

               <section class="nav ">     
                  <a href="sign_in.php"  class="nav-link text-light">Sign in</a>
                  <a href="sign_up.php"  class="nav-link text-light">Sign up</a>
               </section>   
      </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just move the signup section to top and add class order-md-3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
     <div class="container" >

              <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ourNav">
                      <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
             </button>
                    <a href="" class="navbar-brand "> online exam </a>
<section class="nav order-md-3">     
                  <a href="sign_in.php"  class="nav-link text-light">Sign in</a>
                  <a href="sign_up.php"  class="nav-link text-light">Sign up</a>
               </section>   

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center " id="ourNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Your Profile</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Exam</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item "><a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </div>

               
      </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but , brother  sign in & sign up option came  just after navbar brand when it is in full screen.i dont want this.   i want sign in, sign up option at the end of the navbar always rather it is full screen or mediam. 

btw , thanks for your effort brother

Comment: just add 'order-md-3' class to the sign up sign in section.Check above code which is edited now.check this fiddle also https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/Lafk32uc/

Comment: cool.If it is working acknowledge it with green tick so that it will be useful for others who refers this in future.